# Will adsense 'use' comments between the adsense opening and closing tags for ad targeting?

Tags: google-adsense

I've got a simple website on which students of my school can see their timetable. I setup adsense three weeks ago and everything is working fine. But I would like to help adsense.

- Since only a timetable and a few instructions are shown, there is scarcely content to which ads can relate.

Idea:

```
<!- google_ad_section_start –>
<!-- Students like clothing ... and bargains, etc.-->
<!– google_ad_section_end –>
```

Will this work? Or are there other ways to help adsense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The closest you can come is "[section targeting](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=23168)".

> **What is section targeting and how do I implement it?**
>
> Section
>   targeting allows you to suggest sections of your text and HTML content
>   that you'd like us to emphasize or downplay when matching ads to your
>   site's content. By providing us with your suggestions, you can assist
>   us in improving your ad targeting. We recommend that only those
>   familiar with HTML attempt to implement section targeting.
>
> To implement section targeting, you'll need to add a set of special
>   HTML comment tags to your code. These tags will mark the beginning and
>   end of whichever section(s) you'd like to emphasize or de-emphasize
>   for ad targeting.
>
> The HTML tags to emphasize a page section take the following format:
>
> `<!-- google_ad_section_start -->`
>
> `<!-- google_ad_section_end -->`
>
> You can also designate sections you'd like to have ignored by adding a
>   (weight=ignore) to the starting tag:
>
> `<!-- google_ad_section_start(weight=ignore) -->`
>
> With these tags added to your HTML code, your final code may look like
>   the following:
>
> ```
> <html><head><title>Section targeting</title></head>
> <body>
> <!-- google_ad_section_start -->
> ```
>
> This is the text of your webpage. Most of your content resides here.
>
> `<!-- google_ad_section_end -->`
>    
>   ` 
>   You can use section
>   targeting to make suggestions about as many sections of a page as you
>   like. However, please be aware that we can't guarantee results, and
>   that it may take up to 2 weeks before our crawlers take into account
>   any changes you've made to your site.
>
> In order to properly implement this feature, you'll need to include a
>   significant amount of content within the section targeting tags.
>   Including insufficient content may result in less relevant ads or no
>   ads at all. In addition, please keep in mind that this feature should
>   only be used to emphasize significant sections of your site's relevant
>   content. It is against our program policies to manipulate the ad
>   targeting to result in ads that are not relevant to the content of
>   your pages.

Answer (score 1):

You are not "helping adsense" what you are doing though is taking a risk with the account, google is cracking down on sites that have almost no content or sites where there are more ads showing than written content.

What you are referring to is nothing to do with helping adsense, you need to add more content, there has got to be something that you can do to add more content.

Google might see this as trying to trick it into displaying ads that it would not otherwise or an attempt to make higher paying ads display.

Until you can figure out a way to have more written content on the pages i would remove the ad code temporarily so as not to put your adsense account at risk.

Comment: This is the content I am displaying: http://pwslogboek.nl/rooster/demo It is all the users want. What do I have to write a story about? :P

Comment: Im not sure, the thing to remember is that adsense is not suited to all pages, it might still be suited for a site but not ideal having it on certain pages where there is a lack of content.